# How to replicate a column within a data frame?

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate a column of a data frame into the same or a new data frame. My data frame `df` only contains one column:

```
col
1
2
3
4
5
```

I hope to get something like this (another/same data frame, not a matrix):

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3    3
4    4    4    4    4
5    5    5    5    5
```

I tried to create a new data frame by using `new_df <- rep(df[,c(1)],5)`, which I don't understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the column

```
df[paste0('col', 2:5)] <- df$col
```

-ouptut

```
> df
  col col2 col3 col4 col5
1   1    1    1    1    1
2   2    2    2    2    2
3   3    3    3    3    3
4   4    4    4    4    4
5   5    5    5    5    5
```

---

Or if we are using `rep`, the input can be a `list` or `data.frame` instead of a vector i.e. `df[,1]` coerces the data.frame column to a `vector` as by default `drop = TRUE` in `data.frame`.  Instead (if there is only column, either `rep(df, 5)`) or if more than one column subset as `df[1]` (- returns a data.frame with one column) as input in `rep`.  The output will be a `list` of vectors, which we convert to data.frame by wrapping with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(rep(df[1],5))
```

---

Or may also use `replicate`

```
as.data.frame(replicate(5, df$col))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show the code of `rep()` with `list` or `data.frame` input?